# Primefaces Schedule is not passing columnFormat to fullcalendar right

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2, fullcalendar

Using PF 6.1, js 2.2 running on tomcat7

I have a `<p:schedule>` component set up like this:

```
                                <p:schedule
                                    id="mySchedule"
                                    value="#{myBean.agenda}"
                                    widgetVar="myschedule"
                                    scrollTime="08:00:00"
                                    showWeekends="false"
                                    timeZone="#{serverBean.timeZone}"
                                    minTime="07:00:00"
                                    maxTime="21:00:00"
                                    timeFormat="HH:mm"
                                    axisFormat="HH:mm"
                                    slotDuration="00:15:00"
                                    draggable="false"
                                    resizable="false"
                                    view="agendaWeek"
                                    columnFormat="'dddd'"
                                    allDaySlot="false">

                                </p:schedule>
```

When the page renders, this error is being thrown by the JS engine:

```
Syntax error: missing : after property id
at: "HH:mm",timeFormat:"HH:mm",columnFormatOptions:{'dddd'}});});
```

The option 'dddd' is valid for FullCalendar:

> 'dddd'    // like 'Monday',  [ref](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/)
>   A single string alone will set the value for all views.

- The single quotes on `columnFormat="'dddd'"` are not relevant. Removing them just yields another error on the browser console:

  > ReferenceError: dddd is not defined

How should I set `columnFormat` on the XHTML so it gets through right to FullCalendar?

Comment: I think you should remove single quotes and just set like `columnFormat="dddd"`

Comment: @ParkashKumar It was without the single quotes and giving out another error message. I placed the single quotes and reached the error reported above. The problem is how PF is writing the Javascript for Fullcalendar.

Comment: Does the PrimeFaces schedule support `HH:mm` time format? And did you try with `HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: @ParkashKumar 1) why would I want to use `HH:mm` to format a date? - - - - - 2) Whatever is inside the `columnFormat="YOUR_TEXT_HERE"` ends up *ipsis literis* inside `columnFormatOptions:{YOUR_TEXT_HERE}` . So the question stands: what should go inside the `columnFormat` of the `p:schedule` so fullcalendar can understand and render properly.

Comment: Does a plain 'dddd' work in a plain jqueryfullcalendar (without PrimeFaces)? I tried and it did not... Same error, try here :http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/RkWEB/

Comment: @Kukeltje it does. see the documentation for fullcalendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/ - but i have to do it with the primefaces wrapper because of the various bindings and callbacks and ajax and whatnot.

Comment: The docs can state whatever they want, I **tried** and it did not work... Not in the jsfiddle I send and where I changed it to a single string (it is invalid json)

Comment: Ok that jsffilddle is an old jquery fullcalendar. the {} should maybe not be here in this case. PF did not adapt to the single string then. Use the full format then (and file an issue with PF and also that the columnFormatOptions seems the wrong name

Comment: @Kukeltje i'll try the code in your fiddle locally, because my corporate firewall is blocking the loading of resources.

Comment: @Kukeltje "always bet on prime..." .. to have shady documentatioon and poorly written wrappers for third party jquery plugins. :/

Comment: And to have 'extender' functionality to always be able to do what you want. They should not have tried adding every option in an attribute (they would not now, see how they minimized this for jqplot)... (and the docs and showcase are rather good/complete). But you as a developer have an obligation to, learn basics (learn to use google). I found all this out in less than 1 hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143912/discussion-between-mindwin-and-kukeltje).

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces columnFormat does not require you to write full json in case you want headers per view, so

```
  columnFormat="month: 'dddd', week: 'dddd'"
```

would be enough instead of

```
  columnFormat="{month: 'dddd', week: 'dddd'}"
```

PrimeFaces automagically adds the `{}` around the value you enter as can be seen in the [source of the ScheduleRenderer.java](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/schedule/ScheduleRenderer.java#L202). So just entering a single string in there like

```
  columnFormat="'dddd'"
```

results in

```
  columnFormatOptions:{'dddd'}
```

Which is invalid json and that is the error you get... 'dddd' is seen as a key and there is no `:` separator following that after which there should be a value.

You'd get the same error if you'd put the same string in a vanilla jquery fullcalendar.

The only option I see is to either use the extender functionalty, or declare per view.